# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' error, when adding WCF service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am having an issue when trying to add a service reference to my winforms app. Both the service and the app are in the same solution and the service is using iisexpress with the default iisexpress development certificate installed. When I try to add the service reference I get the normal dialogs which find the service and then tell me the certificate is not signed by an authority. I "Ok" that message but then I get this error.

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'.

The web.config for the web service is as follows

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

EDIT----------------

I also get the following messagebox pop up after I accept the certificate.

"There was an error downloading metadata from this address.Please verify that you have entered a valid address"

Also I have found if I change

```
<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

to

```
<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

Then I can suddenly add the reference. Why is this? Surely I need it to be wsHttpsBinding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed this issue.

I needed to change the following config on the server

```
<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

to

```
<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBindingConfig" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration you have `<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />`, which indicates a signed certificate must be used to authenticate the client. For that you need to have a properly signed certificate.

Try using `<transport clientCredentialType="None" />` to circumvent or look at [the various options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httpclientcredentialtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see which one applies to your use case.

Comment: I have changed the clientCredentialType to None rebuilt then tried to add the reference again. However I get the same error.

Comment: You might need to remove the `<message clientCredentialType="UserName" />` entry as well; and to be safe, change `<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">` to `<security mode="None">`.

Comment: How do I then use credentials to sign in to the web service?

Comment: Well, you need to start by having a properly signed certificate. Otherwise, look at the [security mode options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.securitymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see which one you can use.

Comment: I have changed them all to "None" now but still get the same error. I have noticed that I get the following error after I accept the certificate. "There was an error downloading metadata from this address.Please verify that you have entered a valid address"

Comment: Can you verify the service exists on that address? Try using a browser to access it; you should see the service definition.

Comment: I have found that if I change the protocolMapping to basicHttpsBinding I can add the reference. However I was under the impression that I need it to be wsHttpsBinding.